# How can we tell maven surefire not to reuse threads?

Tags: maven

I know how it works with a forked JVM testing setup, but when running testNG tests on threads, if I have 14 tests and set threads to 2, maven will finish one test in the browser and then begin the next test in the same browser, how can i shut that browser down and spawn a new window of chrome for example instead?

**Currently:**

```
-> 1 - > 3 - > 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> 11 -> 13
-> 2 - > 4 - > 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> 12 -> 14
```

**What I want:**

```
-> 1
-> 2
-> 3
-> 4
-> 5
-> 6
-> 7
-> 8
-> 9
-> 10
-> 11
-> 12
-> 13
-> 14
```

I want the threads not to be used, and a new browser spun up with a new thread created, executed 2 at a time when threads == 2.  I am using the following configuration on surefire:

```
  <parallel>methods</parallel>
  <threadCount>${thread.count}</threadCount>
```

Can we tell maven surefire to NOT reuse the same thread/browser but instead create a new one, similar to `<reuseForks>false<reuseForks>`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing but why not using `<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>` as you already mentioned? Have you taken a look at: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Comment: that is for forked JVM process execution right? I am using multi threading within one JVm

Comment: Hi @Jackofspace, any luck with that?